# File-based datastructure for Java

Tags: java, database, svn

For my Java project I am looking for a convenient way to store my data. I have the following requirements:

1. It should be easy to synchronize with subversion (which I use for my Java code and other stuff). So I guess file-based is appropriate.
2. I want to be able to get certain elements without having to read all data into memory. Like in a database ("give me all objects with/without property x", "give me all information about object with certain ID").
3. I want to be able to read and write in this way.

I guess a database is overkill for my purpose, difficult to sync and I have to be admin/root on all machines to install it. (right?)

So I was thinking of using XML, but I heard that XML parsing in Java does not work very well. Or can anyone point me to a good library?

Then I was thinking of CSV. But all examples I saw (here and elsewhere) read the data into memory before processing it, which is not what I want.

I hope you can help me with this problem, because I am not so experienced with Java.

Edit:
Thank you for downvoting this question without any comment. This is not helpful at all because now I have no new information on my problem and I also have no idea what I did wrong with respect to this community's rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Datanucleus (ORM) and use it with an XML Datastore

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/datastores/xml.html